# $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$ is $C^\infty$ and Taylor polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by 
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}} & \textrm{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0), \\
0 & \textrm{ for } (x,y) = (0,0). 
\end{cases}
$$
I'm trying to prove that it is a $C^\infty$-function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and need to calculate the Taylorpolynomial of $f$ of order $n$.

I'm already stuck showing that it is $C^\infty$. My approach is to show that all the partial derivatives exist and are continuous. What I computed for the partial derivatives is the following: 
$$
D^k_1D^l_2f(x,y) = \frac{2^{k+l} x^ky^l}{(x^2+y^2)^{2k+2l}} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}
$$
Therese are continuous outside of $(0,0)$, and for $(0,0)$ I am trying to show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} D^k_1D^l_2f(x,y) = 0$, but without any success. I also tried polar coordinates but I'm not sure if that works. Anyone knows how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation is essentially the same but with less annoying notation in one dimension. Take $f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2} & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$. Now you have the observations:

- If $x \neq 0$ then $f^{(n)}(x)=r_n(x) f(x)$ where $r_n(x)$ is a rational function whose denominator vanishes only at $x=0$.
- You evaluate $f^{(n)}(0)$ using the limit definition and show that it is zero.

To prove these you will want the observation:

- $p(x) e^{-x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ for any polynomial $p$.

To extend to your situation you can just compose with $(x,y) \mapsto x^2+y^2$ which is easily seen to be $C^\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just checking, does $p(x)e^{-x} \to 0$ also hold if $p(x)$ is a rational function? Is this a standard limit or I still have to prove that this is true?

Comment: @Sigurd Yes, because it has at worst polynomial *scale*, i.e. it can be bounded above in magnitude by some polynomial if you stay away from the roots of the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

You will save some effort if you express $f$ as $g\circ h$, with$$\begin{array}{rccc}g\colon&\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}e^{-\frac1{x^2}}&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}\end{array}$$and$$\begin{array}{rccc}h\colon&\mathbb{R}^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&x^2+y^2\end{array}.$$CLearly, $h$ is a $C^\infty$ functions and thereofre if you prove that $g$ is $C^\infty$ too, then $f$ will be $C^\infty$. Now, prove that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\lim_{x\to0}g^{(n)}(x)=0$. It will follow from this that $f$ is indeed $C^\infty$ and that its Taylor polynomial of any order is the null polynomial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a good idea to consider the composition, I hadn't thought about that yet. The Taylor polynomial all equal to null polynomial, is this true around any point $\vec{a}$, or just for the taylor polynomial around $(0,0)$?

Comment: @Sigurd Only around $(0,0)$.